# Arch Linux Installation Grub Problem

Tags: arch-linux

I'm installing arch Linux and I typed in the command

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

And it responded with

```
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
```

What do I do?

Comment: Edit your `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` and set `use_lvmetad = 0`

Comment: I get that message from my Gentoo Linux when it boots. And I'm quite certain it's because at that point in the boot process lvmetad has not started yet. Perhaps in your case /boot is on an lvm volume. Did you check /boot/grub/grub.cfg to see if it looks sane? Note that if / is on an lvm volume you need to make sure your kernel can boot from lvm.

Answer (score 13):

This worried me as well. From some digging about on the [GRUB Arch Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Warning_when_installing_in_chroot):

> Warning when installing in chroot
>
> When installing GRUB on a LVM system in a chroot environment (e.g. during system installation), you may receive warnings like
>
> /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
>
> or
>
> WARNING: failed to connect to lvmetad: No such file or directory. Falling back to internal scanning.
>
> This is because /run is not available inside the chroot. These warnings will not prevent the system from booting, provided that everything has been done correctly, so you may continue with the installation.

So looks like there's no need to worry.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter, you can ignore it.

It just because lvmetad is not running when you boot your arch from live cd.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall os-prober
That made it work for me

Comment: You first need to be able to boot to do that...